# Complex integration along a curve

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, curves

I have to calculate this integral: 
$$
\int_C e^z\,dz
$$
where $C$ is the circle $|z - jπ/2| = π/2$ from the point $z = 0$ to the point $z = jπ$.

I know how to calculate these with circles which central point is at $(0,0)$ but I don't know how it works with this.. So I will be very glad if I got any tips or help.
Thanks!

Comment: The problem here is that you need to specify more detail.  Which direction, and which branch of the curve?

Comment: Oh I forgot to say the direction, it is clockwise. And the points of the curve are z=0 and z=jπ and I need to calculate integral between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the complex version of the fundamental theorem of calculus: $F(z) = e^z$ is an anti-derivative of your $f$, so
$$
\int_C e^z\,dz = F(i\pi) - F(0) = -2.
$$

Answer (score -2):

$e^z$ is an entire function so by Cauchy integral theorem, your integral is 0.

Comment: The curve $C$ is not a closed loop.